# Наследование оператора вывода

Tags: c++

```
    class Vehicle
    {
    public:
      virtual ~Vehicle()=0;
      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vehicle& t){
          os<<"Vehicle"; 
          return os;};
    };
```

От Vehicle наследуются несколько классов, например:

```
class Truck :virtual public Vehicle
{
public:
    Truck();
     ~Truck();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Truck& t {
       os<<"Truck";
       return os;};
};

void main(){
vector<Vehicle*>vehicles;
//{...}заполнение вектора объектами классов, унаследованными от  Vehicle
cout << *vehicles[0];// <--Вывод
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы оператор вывода использовался не от Vehicle, а от производных классов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фокус проделывается не "перегрузкой" оператора (это в принципе невозможно для френдов), а перегрузкой самого метода вывода. Как-то так, например:

```
class Vehicle {
  protected:
    virtual ostream & print(ostream & os) const {
      os << "Vehicle";
      return os;
    }
    public:
      virtual ~Vehicle() {};
      friend ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const Vehicle & v) {
        return v.print(os);
      }
};

class Truck: virtual public Vehicle {
  protected:
    virtual ostream & print(ostream & os) const {
      os << "Truck";
      return os;
    }
};
```